# TextView changes position on buttonClick?

Tags: android, textview

So a quick question...

I've come across a problem that I've never experienced before. 
I have a TextView displaying a message that is in a LinnearLayout with Gravity set to center_horizontal. On a button press - that same TextView's text get swapped with another string from my resources.

BUT, when I press the button the gravity changes (?) and the TextViews position is now left instead of center...

Any ideas of what causes this?

Heres my code: 
String resources:

```
<string name="welcome_message">
    WELCOME, USER!
</string>

<string name="calculating_message">
    CALCULATING ORIENTATION...
</string>
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/welcome_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
public void initializeComponents() {

        //textview
        tvMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

        //button
        btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
            btnGo.setOnClickListener(new btnGoListener());
        }

private class btnGoListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvMessage.setText(R.string.calculating); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your xml and java code ??

Comment: yes, you can look at the code now.

Comment: Show xml code where your `TextView` is, pls.

Comment: Updated it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about the `android:textAlignment="center"` attribute. Your text's alignment is left as default.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/welcome_message"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

And also change `android:layout_width=` to `"match_parent"`

Sorry for bad english. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change in the  string value from resources happens without following proper naming convention guidelines. And Change in the Textview position happens due to two changes layout_gravity and gravity better have a look at the difference between them. I Hope this solves your issue Or better post your source code.